# default firewall rules not executed on gcloud compute engine

Tags: firewall, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I notice something weird behavior on my  gcloud compute engine"
this default firewall rules has no effect:

```
> $ gcloud compute --project "plop" firewall-rules
> describe default-allow-http allowed:
> - IPProtocol: tcp   ports:
>   - '80' creationTimestamp: '2018-07-26T05:17:16.627-07:00' description: '' direction: INGRESS kind: compute#firewall name:
> default-allow-http network:
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plop/global/networks/default
> priority: 1000 selfLink:
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plop/global/firewalls/default-allow-http
> sourceRanges:
> - 0.0.0.0/0 targetTags:
> - http-server
```

And I have add this one:

```
> $ gcloud compute --project "plop" firewall-rules
> describe web allowed:
> - IPProtocol: tcp   ports:
>   - '80' creationTimestamp: '2018-06-26T01:48:18.068-07:00' description: '' direction: INGRESS kind: compute#firewall name: web
> network:
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plop/global/networks/default
> priority: 1000 selfLink:
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plop/global/firewalls/web
> sourceRanges:
> - 0.0.0.0/0
>
```

Seems to me those two rules are identical though, any idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first firewall rule **default-allow-http** is the default one in Google Cloud platform that you will find in any project.
The second one is like the first one it's  ingress allowing http (**Port 80**), the only difference is just the first one is having a [**Target**](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#rule_assignment), The firewall rule applies only to VMs with a matching [**network tag**](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags).

Again the second firewall **web** will be applied to any VMs in the default network, because there is no Target specified.